# OpenSceneGraph osg::Quat: shape not rotating

Tags: rotation, quaternions, openscenegraph

I have a small function to create a new instance of a `WorldObject`.

I want to use `osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform>` for translation and rotation but there is a problem I can't figure out.

I use `setTranslation()` with a `Vec3` which works very well.  But the `Quat` with `makeRotation()` just does nothing.

Here is the code:

```
osg::ref_ptr <osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> getWorldObjectClone(const char*  name, osg::Vec3 position = osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0), osg::Vec3 rotation = osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0))
{
    osg::ref_ptr <osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> tmp = new osg::PositionAttitudeTransform;
    osg::Quat q(0, osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0));
    tmp = dynamic_cast<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform*>(WorldObjects[name]->clone(osg::CopyOp::DEEP_COPY_ALL));
    tmp->setPosition(position);
    q.makeRotate(rotation.x(), 1, 0, 0);
    q.makeRotate(rotation.y(), 0, 1, 0);
    q.makeRotate(rotation.z(), 0, 0, 1);
    tmp->setAttitude(q);
    return tmp;
}
```

I tried rotation = {90,0,0} (degrees) and rotation = {1,0,0} (radians) but both have no effect.  Is there an mistake in how the code is using the `Quat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation method you are using works with radians.
If you want to rotate 90 degrees around the X axis, you need to call:

```
q.makeRotate(osg::PI_2, 1, 0, 0 );
// or the equivalent
q.makeRotate(osg::PI_2, osg::X_AXIS);
```

Keep in mind that *every* call to makeRotate will reset the full quaternion to the given rotation. If you're trying to concatenate several rotations, you have to multiply the corresponding quaternions.
For instance:

```
osg::Quar xRot, yRot;
// rotate 90 degrees around x
xRot.makeRotate(osg::PI_2, osg::X_AXIS);
// rotate 90 degrees around y
yRot.makeRotate(osg::PI_2, osg::Y_AXIS);
// concatenate the 2 into a resulting quat
osg::Quat fullRot = xRot * yRot;
```